# How to get laravel excel import failures when using Queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

what I want is to get validation failures (in afterImport) when the import is finished, I'm getting them successfully when I don't use the ShouldQueue concern, but when I use it, I'm not getting the validation failures in (after import) function.

This is my import code

```
public function import(Request $request) 
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:xlsx'],
        ]);
        Excel::import(new \App\Imports\ProductImport(auth()->user()), request()->file('file'));
        return $this->sendResponse('Import is started!');
    }
```

And this is my import class,

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterImport;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsFailures;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure;

class ProductImport implements ToModel, WithValidation, WithEvents, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading, WithHeadingRow, ShouldQueue,SkipsOnFailure
{
        use SkipsFailures;

    protected $user;


    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterImport::class => function(AfterImport $event) {
                

                dd($event->getConcernable()->failures(), $this->failures());
                // You can customize the notification message and method as per your requirements.
                $this->user->notify(new ImportCompleted($importedCount, $failures));
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the Error ?
    Where is the `ProductImport` constructor ?

Comment: I've removed the code due to the limitation of the code block in StackOverflow, just showing the after event class and the import code

Comment: At least give us the error so we can give you the proper answer !

Comment: what I want is to get validation failures (in afterImport) when the import is finished, I'm getting them successfully when I don't use the ShouldQueue concern, but when I use it, I'm not getting the validation failures in (after import) function.